# @OrderBy annotation cannot order by sub relation

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, openjpa

If There is a relation like this:

```
entity A (one) ---> (many) entity B (one)---->(one) entity C
```

And current JPA entity A has following relation definition:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "A", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("b.c.fieldFromC DESC, field1FromB, field2FromB") // <--- b.c.fieldFromC DESC becomes a problem
private List<B> b_List;
```

Seems `@OrderBy` only valid if b is in a condition(because b is a field of A) but not for any fields of B(sub relations), in short, `@OrderBy` only valid for A.b but not A.b.c

We are using OpenJPA and I know provide like Hibernate can provide sorter so that can include a comparator class, but my question is, is there any spec about `@OrderBy` by sub relation in general JPA 2.0 spec? If not, then, does OpenJPA have any of those sorter implementation? What could be an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is specified in JPA 2.0 specification - @OrdedBy does not support order by attributes of entities that are related to the entities in list:

> A property or field name specified as an orderby_item must correspond
>   to a basic persistent property or field of the associated class or
>   embedded class within it. The properties or fields used in the
>   ordering must correspond to columns for which comparison operators are
>   supported.
>
> The dot (".") notation is used to refer to an attribute within an
>   embedded attribute. The value of each identifier used with the dot
>   notation is the name of the respective embedded field or property.

One alternative is to create Comparator (sort in Java instead of SQL) and use it in custom method that returns list in preferred order.

Comment: Thank you, not supporting attribute of entities is no good here, I finally made a work around to use the Comparator in the getter method when return entity list. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Class A

```
@OrderBy("c_fieldFromC DESC")
private List<B> b_List;
```

Class B

```
@Column(name = "(SELECT field_from_c FROM c WHERE c.id = b.c_id)", insertable = false, updatable = false
private String c_fieldFromC;
```

Comment: Does this work? Do you have any documentation to know how to create Class B that way? The name shloud be the Column name...